# Firefox will not update changes to CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, animation

I am working on a site that is using css animations and I am having some trouble with firefox.
In some instances it seems like firefox is not reading the updated css file and in other places the css updates.  I have tried a few things to clear the cache and did a hard reload to see if the changes in the css would reflect on the site. I went as far as to uninstall and reinstall firefox.  Here is what I have encountered.  The keyframe animation works perfectly in chrome and safari so far (been avoiding IE headaches). I noticed in testing firefox shows one of the text elements about 100px above where it should be. All the values are the same across the browser specific code. The strange part is if I try and change any of the values using firefox prefix it does not change. Say original top is set to 10px and I will change it to 500px, firefox will render it at the same position as 10px. Another reason I thought this might be an issue with firefox not reloading the css file is that I tried commenting off the entire section that animates the text and it will still animate as if I did not comment the code out.  In the other browsers the commented animation would simply not animate.  I did another test by changing the a text color to red instead of white and that change actually updated.

Additionally I use javascript to reverse the animation by removing the class and replacing it with a reverse animation class.  These work fine in chrome and safari as well, but only one of the animated elements works in reverse, but does not change the animation delay to zero in the firefox code.

I could use a fresh pair of eyes to see what exactly going on.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the jsfiddle link. I can add screenshots if that helps but the jsfiddle is probably the easiest to see what I am talking about.
http://jsfiddle.net/JustALittleHeat/A5gMJ/1/

HTML

```
<body>
<div id= "aboutWrapper">
        <div id= "quoteContainer">
        <div id="quoteButton" class= "quoteButton" onclick="changeClass()"     
onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">-</div>
        <h1 id="quotationMarks1" class="quotationMarks1">"</h1>
        <p id ="quote" class ="quote"><em><strong>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp THE BETTER THE   
PEOPLE YOU SURROUND YOURSELF WITH, THE BETTER YOU'RE GOING TO DO, FOR YOURSELF AND THE 
CONSUMER.</strong></em></p><h1 id="quotationMarks2" class="quotationMarks2">"</h1> <h2  
id="cecil" class="cecil">- Cecil Van Tuyl</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="aboutContainer" class="aboutContainer">
        <h1 class="pageParaHeader">About Us</h1>
        <p class="textBody"><strong class="dropCap">V</strong>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp an  
Tuyl Group, Inc. provides management consulting <br> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp services 
to the largest group of privately held automotive dealerships in the United States. With 
offices in Arizona, Kansas, and Texas, the management consulting group works with 
approximately seventy independently operated dealerships nationwide.<br> <br> &nbsp 
&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp The Van Tuyl family has had a long history with the automotive 
industry, starting with Cecil Van Tuyl and a Kansas City Chevrolet dealership in 1955. 
Joined by his son Larry in 1971, they have built a world class management consulting 
company based on the principles of hiring the right people and giving their dealership 
clients the right tools, training and support they need to succeed.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    /*-------------Style Quote Block. NOT IE VERION-----------------------------*/


#aboutWrapper { position:relative; height:400px; width:100%; max-width:800px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;
}

#quoteContainer {position:absolute;  padding-left:20px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:800px; height:200px; 
}

.quoteButton {position:absolute; width:200px; height:30px;top:5px; z-index: 5; cursor:pointer; opacity:0;
}

.quoteButtonMin {position:absolute; width:200px; height:30px;top:5px; z-index: 5; cursor:pointer; opacity:0; color:#069ec7; font-size: 3em; line-height: 15px;

-webkit-animation: buttonMin 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: buttonMin 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: buttonMin 1s ease-in-out; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}



.quoteButtonMin:hover {color:#3ccaf0;}

.quote {position:absolute; width:800px;  color:white; font-size:2em; font-family:"Arial", sans-serif; top:15px; right:0px; 


-webkit-animation: quoteMove 2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-delay:4s; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: quoteMove 2s ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-delay:4s; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: quoteMove 2s ease-in-out; 
animation-delay:4s; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


.quotationMarks1 {position:absolute; color:#069ec7; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10em; top:-103px; left:10px;

-webkit-animation: markMove1 2s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-delay:4s; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: markMove1 2s ease-in-out; 
-moz-animation-delay:4s; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: markMove1 2s ease-in-out; 
animation-delay:4s; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;   
}

.quotationMarks2 {position:absolute; color:#069ec7; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10em;
left:696px; top:-15px;  

-webkit-animation: markMove2 2s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-delay:4s; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: markMove2 2s ease-in-out; 
-moz-animation-delay:4s; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: markMove2 2s ease-in-out; 
animation-delay:4s; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;    
}

.cecil {position:absolute; width:375px; color:white; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:3em; top:120px; left:340px;

-webkit-animation: cecilMove 2s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-delay:4s; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: cecilMove 2s ease-in-out; 
-moz-animation-delay:4s; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: markMove2 2s ease-in-out; 
animation-delay:4s; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}

/*--------------------------------------Button Minimize--------------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes buttonMin {
    0% {opacity:0; width:10px;}
    100%{opacity:1; width:10px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes buttonMin {
    0% {opacity:0; width:10px;}
    100%{opacity:1; width:10px;}
}

@keyframes buttonMin {
    0% {opacity:0; width:10px;}
    100%{opacity:1; width:10px;}
}

/*-----------------------------------Quote Animation------------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes quoteMove {
    0% {-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);opacity:1;}
    45% {opacity:1;}
    50% {-webkit-transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes quoteMove {
    0% {-moz-transform:scale(1,1);opacity:1;}
    45% {opacity:1;}
    50% {-moz-transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    100% {-moz-transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes quoteMove {
    0% {transform:scale(1,1);opacity:1;}
    45% {opacity:1;}
    50% {transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    100% {transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
}

/*--------------------------Quotation Marks 1------------------------------*/

@-webkit-keyframes markMove1 {
    0% {left:10px; top:103; -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:325px;top:-50px;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:-5px;top:-50px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    100% {left:-5px;top:-160px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
}

@-moz-keyframes markMove1 {
    0% {left:10px; top:103; -moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:325px;top:-50px;-moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:-5px;top:-50px;-moz-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    100% {left:-5px;top:-160px;-moz-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
}

@keyframes markMove1 {
    0% {left:10px; top:103; transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:325px;top:-50px;transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:-5px;top:-50px;transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    100% {left:-5px;top:-160px;transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
}

/*-------------------------Quotation Marks 2----------------------------*/

@-webkit-keyframes markMove2 {
    0% {left:696px; top:-15;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:395px;top:-50px;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:30px;top:-50px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    100% {left:30px;top:-160px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
}

@-moz-keyframes markMove2 {
    0% {left:696px; top:-15;-moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:395px;top:-50px;-moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:30px;top:-50px;-moz-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    100% {left:30px;top:-160px;-moz-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
}

@keyframes markMove2 {
    0% {left:696px; top:-15; transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:395px;top:-50px; transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:30px;top:-50px; transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    100% {left:30px;top:-160px; transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
}

/*-----------------------------Cecil Move-------------------*/

@-webkit-keyframes cecilMove {
    0% {left:340px; top:120px; -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
    25% {left:490px;top:120px; -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:490px;top:40px; -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:-30px;top:63px; -webkit-transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    100% {left:-30px;top:-45px; -webkit-transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
}


@keyframes cecilMove {
    0% {left:340px; top:120px; transform: scale(1,1); }
    25% {left:490px;top:120px; transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:490px;top:40px; transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:-30px;top:63px; transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    100% {left:-30px;top:-45px; transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
}

@-moz-keyframes cecilMove {
    0% {left:340px; top:120px; -moz-transform: scale(1,1); }
    25% {left:490px;top:120px; -moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    50% {left:490px;top:40px; -moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    90% {left:-30px;top:63px; -moz-transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    100% {left:-30px;top:-45px; -moz-transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
}


/*-------------------- Reverse Animation Classes-------------*/

.quoteR {position:absolute; width:800px;  color:white; font-size:2em; font-family:"Arial", sans-serif; top:15px; right:0px; 


-webkit-animation: quoteMoveR 2.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: .45s;
-moz-animation: quoteMoveR 2.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-delay: .45s;
animation: quoteMove 2.5s ease-in-out; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: .45s;
}


.quoteButtonMinR {position:absolute; width:200px; height:30px;top:5px; z-index: 5; cursor:pointer; opacity:1; color:#069ec7; font-size: 3em; line-height: 15px;

-webkit-animation: buttonMinR 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: buttonMinR 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: buttonMinR 1s ease-in-out; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.quotationMarks1R {position:absolute; color:#069ec7; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10em; top:-103px; left:10px;

-webkit-animation: markMove1R 2.5s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: markMove1R 2.5s ease-in-out; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: markMove1R 2.5s ease-in-out; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;   
}

.quotationMarks2R {position:absolute; color:#069ec7; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10em;
left:696px; top:-15px;  

-webkit-animation: markMove2R 2.5s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: markMove2R 2.5s ease-in-out; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: markMove2 2.5s ease-in-out; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;    
}

.cecilR {position:absolute; width:375px; color:white; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:3em; top:120px; left:340px;

-webkit-animation: cecilMoveR 2.5s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: cecilMoveR 2.5s ease-in-out; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: markMove2 2.5s ease-in-out; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}

/*-----------------------------Button Animation Reverse--------------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes buttonMinR {
    0%{opacity:1; width:10px;}
    100% {opacity:0; width:10px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes buttonMinR {
    0%{opacity:1; width:10px;}
    100% {opacity:0; width:10px;}
}

@keyframes buttonMinR {
    0%{opacity:1; width:10px;}
    100% {opacity:0; width:10px;}
}

/*--------------------------------Quote Reverse-----------------------------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes quoteMoveR {
    0% {-webkit-transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    50% {-webkit-transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    55% {opacity:1;}
    100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes quoteMoveR {
    0% {-moz-transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    50% {-moz-transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    55% {opacity:1;}
    100% {-moz-transform:scale(1,1);opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes quoteMoveR {
    0% {transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    50% {transform:scale(0,0);opacity:0;}
    55% {opacity:1;}
    100% {transform:scale(1,1);opacity:1;}
}

/*-----------------------------------Quotation Marks 1 Reverse-----------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes markMove1R {
    0% {left:-5px;top:-160px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    10% {left:-5px;top:-50px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    50% {left:325px;top:-50px;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:10px; top:103; -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
}

@-moz-keyframes markMove1R {
    0% {left:-5px;top:-160px;-moz-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    10% {left:-5px;top:-50px;-moz-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    50% {left:325px;top:-50px;-moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:10px; top:103; -moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
}

@-keyframes markMove1R {
    0% {left:-5px;top:-160px;transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    10% {left:-5px;top:-50px;transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    50% {left:325px;top:-50px;transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:10px; top:103;transform: scale(1,1);}
}

/*----------------------------------Quotation Marks 2 Reverse-------------------------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes markMove2R {
    0% {left:30px;top:-160px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    10% {left:30px;top:-50px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    50% {left:395px;top:-50px;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:696px; top:-15;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}   
}

@-moz-keyframes markMove2R {
    0% {left:30px;top:-160px;-moz-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    10% {left:30px;top:-50px;-moz-transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    50% {left:395px;top:-50px;-moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:696px; top:-15;-moz-transform: scale(1,1);}   
}

@keyframes markMove2R {
    0% {left:30px;top:-160px;transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    10% {left:30px;top:-50px;transform: scale(0.45,0.45);}
    50% {left:395px;top:-50px;transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:696px; top:-15;transform: scale(1,1);}   
}

/*-----------------------------Cecil Move Reverse-----------------------------*/
@-webkit-keyframes cecilMoveR {
    0% {left:-30px;top:-45px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    10% {left:-30px;top:63px;-webkit-transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    50% {left:490px;top:40px;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    75% {left:490px;top:120px;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:340px; top:120px;-webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }    
}

@-moz-keyframes cecilMoveR {
    0% {left:-30px;top:-45px;-moz-transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    10% {left:-30px;top:63px;-moz-transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    50% {left:490px;top:40px;-moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    75% {left:490px;top:120px;-moz-transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:340px; top:120px;-moz-transform: scale(1,1); }    
}

@keyframes cecilMoveR {
    0% {left:-30px;top:-45px;transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    10% {left:-30px;top:63px;transform: scale(0.35,0.35);}
    50% {left:490px;top:40px;transform: scale(1,1);}
    75% {left:490px;top:120px;transform: scale(1,1);}
    100% {left:340px; top:120px;transform: scale(1,1); }    
}



/*-----------About Us IE Version Not setup-----------------------*/

.aboutContainer {position:relative; float:right; margin-right: 2.5%;width:400px; color:#069ec7; opacity:0;

-webkit-animation: aboutShow 2s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-delay:5s; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation: aboutShow 2s ease-in-out; 
-moz-animation-delay:5s; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation: aboutShow 2s ease-in-out; 
animation-delay:4s; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


.aboutContainerR {position:relative; float:right; margin-right: 2.5%;width:400px; color:#069ec7; opacity:0;

-webkit-animation: aboutShowR 2s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
-moz-animation: aboutShowR 2s ease-in-out; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation: aboutShowR 2s ease-in-out; 
animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.pageParaHeader {font-family: arial; font-size: 3em; color:#069ec7;   
}

.textBody {position: relative; margin-top: -20px; color:white;
}

.dropCap {position:absolute; font-size:2.5em; top:-4px;color:#069ec7;
}

@-webkit-keyframes aboutShow {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    75% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes aboutShow {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    75% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes aboutShow {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    75% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes aboutShowR{
    0% {opacity:1;}
    25% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes aboutShowR{
    0% {opacity:1;}
    25% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}


@keyframes aboutShowR{
    0% {opacity:1;}
    25% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}

body {background:black;}
```

Javascript

```
function changeClass() {


    if (document.getElementById("quotationMarks1").className === "quotationMarks1") 
   {document.getElementById("quotationMarks1").className = "quotationMarks1R";
    document.getElementById("quotationMarks2").className = "quotationMarks2R";
    document.getElementById("quote").className = "quoteR";
    document.getElementById("cecil").className = "cecilR";
    document.getElementById("aboutContainer").className ="aboutContainerR";
    document.getElementById("quoteButton").className ="quoteButtonMin";    
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("quotationMarks1").className = "quotationMarks1";
        document.getElementById("quotationMarks2").className = "quotationMarks2";
        document.getElementById("quote").className = "quote";
        document.getElementById("cecil").className = "cecil";
        document.getElementById("aboutContainer").className ="aboutContainer";
        document.getElementById("quoteButton").className ="quoteButtonMinR";

        document.getElementById("quotationMarks1").style.webkitAnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("quotationMarks2").style.webkitAnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("quote").style.webkitAnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("cecil").style.webkitAnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("aboutContainer").style.webkitAnimationDelay = "0s";

        document.getElementById("quotationMarks1").style.mozAnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("quotationMarks2").style.mozAnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("quote").style.mozAnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("cecil").style.mozAnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("aboutContainer").style.mozAnimationDelay = "0s";

        document.getElementById("quotationMarks1").style.AnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("quotationMarks2").style.AnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("quote").style.AnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("cecil").style.AnimationDelay = "0s";
        document.getElementById("aboutContainer").style.AnimationDelay = "0s";


        document.getElementById("quoteButton").className ="quoteButton";  
    }

}

function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("quotationMarks1").style.color = "#3ccaf0";
    document.getElementById("quotationMarks2").style.color = "#3ccaf0";
}

function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("quotationMarks1").style.color = "#069ec7";
    document.getElementById("quotationMarks2").style.color = "#069ec7";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to change the animation name from `markMove2` to `cecilMove`

```
.cecil { ... animation: cecilkMove2 2s ease-in-out; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/A5gMJ/3/)

Also, you should use javascript variables to keep track of your DOM elements instead of getting them by their ID every time. It performs better, is easier to upkeep, and is easier to write as well

Comment: Thanks for the help and also the tip for using the variables in javascript instead of getting their document id.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong part of the code. I thought firefox was reading from its pre-fixed animation syntax, but it was reading or applying the standard animation syntax.

Comment: The javascript variables do not seem to be working. Is there something missing in the demo, because it should reverse the animation and have a mouse-over and mouse-out event.

Comment: @justalittleheat Just change `No wrap - in <head>` to `No wrap - in <body>` to the left of the jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/A5gMJ/3/